# Finding indexes in 2d list with conditionals

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list

I need to find the index in a 2d array where the number is either greater than the numbers to the left and right and less than the numbers above and below or vice versa.

I know I'll need two for loops one for columns one for rows, I'm given number x and I need to compare it to the numbers in the 2d array to find the indexes.

```
list = [[1,4,6,7,8],
        [2,4,6,7,8],
        [1,4,6,7,8],
        [1,4,6,7,8],
        [2,4,6,7,8],
        [6,4,6,7,8]]
```

If I'm given 4 as x I need to find the indexes in the 2d list where to the left, right, up and down or vice versa the other numbers are greater than or less than 4. Can someone please offer a solution

```
list = [[1, 4, 6, 7, 8],
        [2, 4, 6, 7, 8],
        [1, 4, 6, 7, 8],
        [1, 4, 6, 7, 8],
        [2, 4, 6, 7, 8],
        [6, 4, 6, 7, 8]]

x = [x for x in list if 4 in x][0]
print('The index is (%d,%d)' % (list.index(x), x.index(4)))
```

With that attempt it will only give me the first index but I need to check the entire array and use an if statement to check for the greater than less than problem.

Comment: Not a homework service, meet us half way with an attempted solution.

Comment: Attempt added to the question

Answer (score 0):

Will this do ?...

```
x = int(input('Enter x: '))
data = [[1, 4, 6, 7, 8],
        [2, 4, 6, 7, 8],
        [1, 4, 6, 7, 8],
        [1, 4, 6, 7, 8],
        [2, 4, 6, 7, 8],
        [6, 4, 6, 7, 8]]

dataTranspose = list(zip(*data))

for each_row_number in range(0, len(data)):

    tempRow = list(enumerate(data[each_row_number]))
    maxIndex, maxVal = max(tempRow, key=lambda eachPair: eachPair[1])
    minIndex, minVal = min(tempRow, key=lambda eachPair: eachPair[1])

    if x == maxVal:
        if x == min(dataTranspose[maxIndex]):
            print(' found another at: (' + str(each_row_number) + ', ' + str(maxIndex) + ')')
    elif x == minVal:
        if x == max(dataTranspose[minIndex]):
            print(' found another at: (' + str(each_row_number) + ', ' + str(minIndex) + ')')
```

Example run:

```
Enter x: 8
 found another at: (0, 4)
 found another at: (1, 4)
 found another at: (2, 4)
 found another at: (3, 4)
 found another at: (4, 4)
 found another at: (5, 4)
```

Example run:

```
Enter x: 4
 found another at: (5, 1)
```

Example run:

```
Enter x: 6
```

(No result in this 3rd example as for x = 6, either of given conditions don't satisfy anywhere in 2d list).

Comment: Thanks a lot tkhurana96 that looks to be pretty much what I'm looking for

Comment: @mcfellows great if it was helpful for you